# "Gross Margin" vs "Gross Profit Margin" in English

Tags: terminology

This is a question about financial terms and definitions in English.

`Gross Margin = Revenue - COGS`

`Gross Profit Margin = (Revenue - COGS) / COGS`

In the first equation we also mean `Profit` (`Gross Profit Margin = Revenue - COGS`), don't we?
Why does adding a word `Profit` (in Gross **Profit** Margin) turns a sum of money `Revenue - COGS` into a ratio `(Revenue - COGS) / COGS`?

[Gross Profit Margin Definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/gross_profit_margin.asp)

[Gross Margin Definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/grossmargin.asp)

Comment: Good question.  Where did you see those two terms **together**?

Comment: @RonJohn These are just definitions. Maybe they are not generally accepted. I don't know whether they are used together or not.

Comment: We can't rationally comment on terms that you might have just pulled randomly out of the air.  Show us where you got the terms.

Comment: @RonJohn I added links

Comment: I think the author and editor of those two links (same people) didn't pay attention.

Comment: Daniel, you didn't copy the ratio correctly from the provided link. It's (Net Sales-COGS)/Net Sales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finance (and other professions I'm sure) often uses terms and phrases interchangeably and inconsistently, so it's not a function of the english language, but a function of these terms being used by fallable humans. "Gross profit" and "Gross margin" can be synonymous, and some use "gross margin" to mean the *ratio*. So it's not always clear exactly what these mean.

If you are confused by a term or phrase being used inconsistently, look at the *context* to see what it's referring to. For example, if an article says "Gizmo's gross margin was 22%", then obviously it's talking about a ratio.